# Как передвигать обьект мышкой

Tags: javascript

есть например `div` как передвигать его мышкой? всмысле чтобы двигался как мышка, был под мышкой, незнаю как обьяснить, всмысле как `drag` только без `drag` а как `hover`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
const cursor = document.querySelector('.cursor');

document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', e => {
  cursor.style.left = e.clientX + 'px';
  cursor.style.top = e.clientY + 'px';
});
```

```css
.cursor {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="cursor"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Вариант на jQuery.

Плюс этого варианта в том, что элемент вместе с курсором уходит за пределы экрана в случае, если курсор покидает видимую часть.

```js
$(document).mousemove(
  function(position) {
    $("#cursor").show();
    $("#cursor").css('left', (position.pageX - 10) + 'px').css('top', (position.pageY - 10) + 'px');
  }
).mouseleave(function() {
  $("#cursor").hide();
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#cursor {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  top: -20px;
  left: -20px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cursor"></div>
```

Comment: На `body` лучше не вешать обработчики, связанные с мышкой или касаниями. Потому что `body` может быть меньше документа. В вашем случае например у него есть отступ и есть небольшой баг в начале. Достаточно просто заменить на `$(document).....`. Это особенно важно при создании ползунков, скролов и так далее, когда нажатая мышь может уходить за пределы браузера без отпускания, и затем возвращаться. В случае с документом поведение ползунка не будет прерываться.